# python: List all subdirectories recursively?

Tags: python

I have a root directory `root_dir` and need to write a method `subdirs=list_subdirs(root_dir)` that would return all subdirectories recursively in a form:

```
/subdir1
/subdir1/subsubdir1
/subdir1/subsubdir2
/subdir1/subsubdir3
/subdir2
/subdir2/subsubdir1
etc...
```

Is `os.walk()` the right way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like this does the trick:

```
def list_subdirs(in_path):
    subdirs = []
    for x in os.walk(in_path):
        subdirs.append(x[0])
    return subdirs
```

Comment: Can this be enhanced?